# How to set status of test step by groovy dispatch script?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have dispatch script which checking content of response and validate it. I want to, this script set status of chosen test step in chosen test case as 'OK' or 'FAILED'. I googled solutions but none of them work, and my knowledge is insufficient at this time to solve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I think its a read only thing. why don't you rerun so it becomes automatically PASS/Fail.

Comment: Or you could store the result in a [custom property](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties/) if you want to set it manually.